# Sails.js Sorting not working?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Trying to sort output in sails in my service:

```
BravaStatus.find({limit: 1, sort : 'ID DESC'}).exec(function(err, statuses) {
```

Tried `'ID ASC'`, tried `sort : {'ID' : 1}` but no luck.

When i list the output, it always starts with ID 25, while I know that the latest ID is 45 (or higher). 
How do i get the latest added record?

Comment: What adapter are you using? Are you sure key is proper formatted (_id,id,_ID,ID) ? Have you tried {sort: {id: 0}} ?

Comment: I dont know, whatever is default? I think that's the membased storage? Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you shold try sorting this way.
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/sort

```
BravaStatus.find({limit: 1}).sort('ID DESC').exec(function(err, statuses) {
    if(err){
        //handle error
    }else{
        //do something with statuses
    }
});
```

Comment: Did do that, no change. Tried .sort('ID ASC'), no change.

Comment: BravaStatus.find({limit: 1}).sort('ID ASC').exec(function(err, statuses) {

Comment: Well, actually the ID starts from 1, so curious why it's bringing ID 25 as the only record?

Comment: Well, the ID increments as I add new records, but it appears to be in the exact middle, not the first or the last record!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
   .sort({ id: 'desc' })
```